# SaveFileDialog InitialDirectory

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have an Outlook 2013 Addin written with VSTO and VS2013.  I have a save file dialog where I set Initial Directory to a network mount.  Saving to the path with `MailItem.SaveAs()` works, but when I use it with `saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "W:/etc/etc/";`  I just get my Documents library as  the Initial Directory.  Why might it not work?

Here is the relevant code:

```
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = filename;
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path;
        saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = false;
        saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "\".mht\"";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "\"MHT Files|*.mht|All Files|*.*\"";

        DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

That's all the pertinant code.  FileName works fine, and path is in the format "W:/Folder/Folder/"

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `path = @"W:\Folder\Folder\"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article about String literals

You should either use double back slashes if you want one backslash

```
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "W:\\etc\\etc\\";
```

or use the @ sign:

```
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"W:\etc\etc\";
```

Also you should set the RestoreDirectory in order to set the working directory back to your application directory.
Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference

```
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

Comment: Even though single slashes work for MailItem.SaveAs(), for InitialDirectory I need backslashs?

Comment: I think it doesnt matter if you have forward or back slashes, c# will convert it to backslash internally. But the problem is that you need to make it a litteral.

Comment: I tried that way and it still didn't give me the correct initial directory

Comment: Seems InitialDirectory does not accept / in the path but requires backslash
See answer below

Comment: I tried the backslash method and still had problems.  I checked the initial directory directly before the call and even with backslashes it did not work

EDIT:  I got it working, some logic was messed up

Answer (score 3):

Seems InitialDirectory does not accept / in the path but requires backslash

This example works for me.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.FileName = "c:/temp/somefilename.txt";
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\temp\\";
saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = false;
saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "\".mht\"";
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "\"MHT Files|*.mht|All Files|*.*\"";

DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```